# Ruby on Rails: date search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, date

Quick question. I am trying to set up a page that searches a database using a start date, end date and keywords. If i was to search 19-07-2012, the path would look like

search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&project%5Bstart_date%5D=19-07-2012&project%5Bend_date%5D=&%5Bstatus%5D=&keywords=

and all results would show. However when I search keywords, the search works. I can't see where I'm going wrong.

```
<h1>Search</h1>




<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
Start Date :

<%#= text_field_tag :start_date, params[:start_date] %></br>

<div class="field">

<%= datepicker_input "project","start_date" %></br>
</div>

End Date :

<%#= text_field_tag :end_date, params[:end_date] %></br>
<%= datepicker_input "project","end_date" %></br>


Status :

<%= select(@projects, :status, Project.all.map {|p| [p.status]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:status]) %></br>

Keywords :

<%= text_field_tag :keywords, params[:keywords] %></br>

<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>

<% end %>
```

Contoller:

```
def search



@project_search = Project.search(params[:start_date], params[:end_date], params[:keywords]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginated_for_index(per_page, page)

   @project = Project.new(params[:project])

respond_to do |format|
      format.html # search.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @project }
    end

end
```

EDIT:

When I search with the character "q" as a keyword, and the start date as 25-07-2012, the sql looks like this

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "project"=>{"start_date"=>"25-07-2012", "end_date"=>""}, "status"=>"", "keywords"=>"q"}
  Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" 
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects" WHERE (client LIKE '%%' AND industry LIKE '%%' AND role LIKE '%%' AND tech LIKE '%%' AND business_div LIKE '%%' AND project_owner LIKE '%%' AND exception_pm LIKE '%%' AND status LIKE '%%' AND start_date LIKE '%%' AND end_date LIKE '%%' AND keywords LIKE '%q%')
```

This only seems to search on the keyword "q". When I remove the keyword and leave the date in, the sql looks like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "project"=>{"start_date"=>"25-07-2012", "end_date"=>""}, "status"=>"", "keywords"=>""}
  Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
```

Thanks in advance for any help given!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my own problem. I changed my application.js file and my search view.

Application.js:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#start_date').val("");
    jQuery('#start_date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
});

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#end_date').val("");
    jQuery('#end_date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
});
```

Search view:

```
Start Date :
<%= text_field_tag("start_date") %></br>

End Date :
<%= text_field_tag("end_date") %></br>
```

My application now searches with a start and an end date.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is correct, you expect to call

```
Project.search(start_date, end_date, keywords)
```

In your example, the params come in

```
project: {
  start_date: "25-07-2012",
  end_date: ""
},
keywords: "q"
```

But you call

```
 Project.search(params[:start_date], params[:end_date], params[:keywords])
```

If your logs are correct you should be calling

```
 Project.search(params[:project][:start_date], params[:project][:end_date], params[:keywords])
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I got this error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: then I think your quote from the logs must be wrong. `"project"=>{"start_date"=>"25-07-2012", "end_date"=>""}`